# How would i silence the output of libcurl without feeding to /dev/null?

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

How would i stop:

```
* Trying <ip address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.com (<ip address>) port 443 (#0)
> POST /test/ HTTP/1.1
```

from showing in cmd output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options should help:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
```

If you don't need the returned document/file, define a `write_callback` callback function:

```
static size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
    /*
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, static_cast<FILE*>(userdata));
    return written;
    */
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

And set the options to redirect the output to your callback function:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, nullptr);
```

Comment: sorry but would it be possible to hide the json returned aswell? e.g {"message": "Unknown Channel"}

Comment: @versity Added example